# Rolling sum with strings

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe containing strings, such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('some_string')})

    col1
0     s
1     o    
2     m
3     e
4     _
5     s
...
```

I'm looking for a way to apply a rolling window on `col1` and join the strings in a certain window size. Say for instance `window=3`, I'd like to obtain (with no minimum number of observations):

```
     col1
0     s
1     so
2     som
3     ome
4     me_
5     e_s
6     _st
7     str
8     tri
9     rin
10    ing
```

I've tried the obvious solutions with `rolling` which fail at handling object types:

```
df.col1.rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum()
df.col1.rolling(3, min_periods=0).apply(''.join)
```

Both raise:

> cannot handle this type -> object

Is there a generalisable approach to do so (not using `shift` to match this specific case of `w=3`)?

Comment: rolling only can handle numeric types and that too, the output of calculation for the window should be single value.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be so... I've also tried to come up with a hacky solution as you say @jezrael , which is also turning out to be pretty tricky

Comment: OK, I think if you really think it is problem with my second answer, be free edit you, undelete and I can remove it from my answer.

Comment: @yatu - It was my second idea, so do you think I  dont write my solution, if not post your answer? But nevemind, it is up to you, what do you do now.

Comment: ya, here is my problem too similar to your solution (if more data, you are not problem correct it). So I have no problem in this situtation remove it from my answer, only you have to create answer

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about shifting the series?

```
df.col1.shift(2).fillna('') + df.col1.shift().fillna('') + df.col1
```

Generalizing to any number:

```
pd.concat([df.col1.shift(i).fillna('') for i in range(3)], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: As mentioned, `not using shift to match this specific case of w=3`

Comment: Sorry, I was too slow to add the dynamic version.

Comment: Nice approach @IanS

Answer (score 2):

Rolling [works only with numbers](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb00deb94500205fcb27a33cc1d0df79a9727f8b/pandas/core/window.py#L192):

> ```
> def _prep_values(self, values=None, kill_inf=True):
>         if values is None:
>             values = getattr(self._selected_obj, 'values', self._selected_obj)
>         # GH #12373 : rolling functions error on float32 data
>         # make sure the data is coerced to float64
>         if is_float_dtype(values.dtype):
>             values = ensure_float64(values)
>         elif is_integer_dtype(values.dtype):
>             values = ensure_float64(values)
>         elif needs_i8_conversion(values.dtype):
>             raise NotImplementedError...
>     ...
>     ...
> ```

So you should construct it manually. Here is one of the possible variants with simple list comprehensions (maybe there is a more Pandas-ish way exists):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('some_string')})
pd.Series([
    ''.join(df.col1.values[max(i-2, 0): i+1])
    for i in range(len(df.col1.values))
])
```

> ```
> 0       s
> 1      so
> 2     som
> 3     ome
> 4     me_
> 5     e_s
> 6     _st
> 7     str
> 8     tri
> 9     rin
> 10    ing
> dtype: object
> ```

Comment: Yes, I guess recurring to a list-comp was the alternative I had in mind too, as couldn't come up with anything else either. Thanks for sharing the snippet where it is mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.Series.cumsum` seems like working (although bit of inefficient):

```
df['col1'].cumsum().str[-3:]
```

Output:

```
0       s
1      so
2     som
3     ome
4     me_
5     e_s
6     _st
7     str
8     tri
9     rin
10    ing
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes I also thought of this. The problem is that this will be very inefficient in terms of memory usage, as the slicing only takes place after having computed the cumulative sum over all previous strings

Comment: This works only if the values are characters. In which case, a stride trick on the total sum might work better.