# how do you go though data frame values in chunks and combine them?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
Metric  ProcId  TimeStamp               Value
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    1.4453125
CPU     proce_126   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.058320373
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.095274389
CPU     proce_000   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.019654088
CPU     proce_144   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.019841269
CPU     proce_1     Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.234741792
CPU     proce_100   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    5.32945776
CPU     proce_57777 Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.25390625
CPU     proce_0000  Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.019349845
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.019500781
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    2.32421875
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    68.3903656
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.057781201
CPU     proce_123   Mar-11-2022 11:00:00    0.416666627
```

This is just a sample dataframe; the actual dataframe is in thousands of rows. I need to go though this dataframe in chunks the `ProdID` column and I need to create a string combining these `ProdID` in chunks for each iteration.

For example the string needs to be like this given the chunk size 3:

```
proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_111%22%29
```

Please note after the 3rd chunk, we need to add `%22%29`. After the first ad second we need to add `%22%2C%2`.

I can do something like this to print out the chunks:

```
n = 3 #size of chunks
chunks = [] #list of chunks

for i in range(0, len(id), n): 
    chunks.append(id[i:i + n])
```

I am not sure how would I combine these 3 items in one string and add the others strings at the end.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by chunk, can you provide a full output?

Comment: @mozway, until I go through all of the procid, I need to create a string of of values as I have listed on the question. Number of proc ids separatged by strings

Comment: I think you need to explain what you want more. The output you wrote looks like you are combining any 3 unique product values in a string with specific separators. If you explain more, people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*avoid iterating through your data frame in a for loop. your performance is almost guaranteed to be poorer than if you used some combination of `groupby`, `merge`, `shift` and other array oriented numpy or pandas operations*

Make chunk ids out of your dataframe through integer division over the index (assumes incremental index values)

```py
chunk_size = 3
df['ChunkId'] = df.index // chunk_size
```

add the suffix to each ProcId to create a new column `ProcEnds`, then join these within each group.

```py
df['ProcEnds'] =  (df.ProcId + '%22%2C%2').where(
  df.index % chunk_size != chunk_size - 1, 
  df.ProcId + '%22%29')
# note DataFrame.where replaces values with other when cond is False

df['ChunkString'] = df.groupby('ChunkId').ProcEnds.transform(lambda x: x.str.cat())
```

Optionally, drop the `ChunkId` & `ProcEnds` columns to get an output with only additional column `ChunkString`

```py
df = df.drop(columns=['ChunkId', 'ProcEnds'])
```

`df` now outputs:

```
   Metric       ProcId           TimeStamp      Value                                           ChunkString
0     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   1.445312     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
1     CPU    proce_126 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.058320     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
2     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.095274     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
3     CPU    proce_000 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019654       proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
4     CPU    proce_144 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019841       proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
5     CPU      proce_1 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.234742       proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
6     CPU    proce_100 2022-03-11 11:00:00   5.329458  proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
7     CPU  proce_57777 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.253906  proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
8     CPU   proce_0000 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019350  proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
9     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019501     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
10    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   2.324219     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
11    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00  68.390366     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
12    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.057781                    proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
13    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.416667                    proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
```

#### update

google colab notebook showing the output with sample data
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f9ZHXE2ATZXD2qWsoATxEWABIBt0tMRN?usp=sharing

#### update 2

OP asked:

> quick question. can we group this based on df['Metric']? For example, it would be CPU, Memory. I would need ChunkString based on CPU or memory?

to apply this transformation within each Metric Group, it is easiest to contain the transformation logic inside a function and apply that on the data.

extra care needs to be made to preserve the original indexing.

```py
def transform(frame):
  _df = frame.reset_index(drop=True)
  _df['ChunkId'] = _df.index // chunk_size
  _df['ProcEnds'] =  (_df.ProcId + '%22%2C%2').where(
    _df.index % chunk_size != chunk_size - 1, 
    _df.ProcId + '%22%29')
  _df['ChunkString'] = _df.groupby('ChunkId').ProcEnds.transform(lambda x: x.str.cat())
  return _df.drop(columns=['ChunkId', 'ProcEnds'])
idx = df.index
df.groupby('Metric').apply(transform).set_index(idx)
```

*produces the same output as earlier, elided for brevity.*

Comment: ChunkString is not showing as appennding for the number of chunksize. I ran this code, there is only one procId in ChunkString. proce_123%22%2C%2

Comment: @user1471980, i'm not sure why you're not seeing the proc ids aggregated.

Comment: here's a google colab with this code showing the output I get. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f9ZHXE2ATZXD2qWsoATxEWABIBt0tMRN?usp=sharing

Comment: quick question. can we group this based on df['Metric']? For example, it would be CPU, Memory. I would need ChunkString based on CPU or memory?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do that would be to contain all this logic in a transformation function accepting a dataframe as parameter. Then group your data by  `Metric`, reset the index within each group, since we use to bound the chunks, and then apply the function generating

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python integer division (`//`) to form the index into groups of N:

```
N = 3
df['ChunkString'] = df.groupby(df.index//N)['ProcId'].transform(lambda x: '%22%2C%2'.join(x.tolist() + ['']*(N-len(x))) + ('%22%29' if len(x) == N else ''))
```

Notes:

- `x.tolist() + ['']*(N-len(x))` just converts `x` to a list, and pads it with empty items until it reaches length `N`

Output

```
>>> df
   Metric       ProcId           TimeStamp      Value                                           ChunkString
0     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   1.445312     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
1     CPU    proce_126 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.058320     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
2     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.095274     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
3     CPU    proce_000 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019654       proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
4     CPU    proce_144 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019841       proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
5     CPU      proce_1 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.234742       proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
6     CPU    proce_100 2022-03-11 11:00:00   5.329458  proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
7     CPU  proce_57777 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.253906  proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
8     CPU   proce_0000 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019350  proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
9     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019501     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
10    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   2.324219     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
11    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00  68.390366     proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
12    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.057781                    proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
13    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.416667                    proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
```

With `N = 5`:

```
>>> df
   Metric       ProcId           TimeStamp      Value                                                                           ChunkString
0     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   1.445312   proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%29
1     CPU    proce_126 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.058320   proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%29
2     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.095274   proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%29
3     CPU    proce_000 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019654   proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%29
4     CPU    proce_144 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019841   proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%29
5     CPU      proce_1 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.234742  proce_1%22%2C%2proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
6     CPU    proce_100 2022-03-11 11:00:00   5.329458  proce_1%22%2C%2proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
7     CPU  proce_57777 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.253906  proce_1%22%2C%2proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
8     CPU   proce_0000 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019350  proce_1%22%2C%2proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
9     CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.019501  proce_1%22%2C%2proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
10    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   2.324219                  proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
11    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00  68.390366                  proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
12    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.057781                  proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
13    CPU    proce_123 2022-03-11 11:00:00   0.416667                  proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chunk_size = 3
list_of_proc_ids = []
# First, generate a list of the procIds
for obj in range(0, len(id)):
    list_of_proc_ids.append(procId) # Not sure how you're appending this, guessing you use a slice on the string line?

final_str = ''
# Then enumerate through that list, adding a unique ending at every third
for index, obj in enumerate(list_of_proc_ids]:
    final_str += str(obj)
    if (index + 1) % chunk_size == 0: # Checks if divisible by 3, accounting for 0 index
        final_str += '%22%29'
    else:
        final_str += '%22%2C%2'
```

Comment: your code starts with one proc_id, then goes to 2, then 3 and so on. I have a thousand of items in list_of_proc_ids. Until I go throuch each one, I need final_str to include 10 (what ever the chunk size picked) proc_ids

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy.apply`:

```
N = 3
out = (df.groupby(df.index//N)['ProcId']
         .apply(lambda x: '%22%2C%2'.join(x)+'%22%29')
       )
```

output (as Series):

```
0       proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
1         proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29
2    proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29
3       proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
4                        proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29
Name: ProcId, dtype: object
```

Or output as list:

```
# out.to_list()
['proce_123%22%2C%2proce_126%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29',
 'proce_000%22%2C%2proce_144%22%2C%2proce_1%22%29',
 'proce_100%22%2C%2proce_57777%22%2C%2proce_0000%22%29',
 'proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29',
 'proce_123%22%2C%2proce_123%22%29']
```

##### older answer before question update

For an efficiency, use a vectorial approach:

```
import numpy as np
N = 3

# map code every N procid
s = np.where(np.arange(len(df))%N < N-1, '%22%2C%2', '%22%29')

# concatenate strings
out = (df['ProcId']+'_'+s).str.cat()
```

Output: `'proce_123_%22%2C%2proce_126_%22%2C%2proce_123_%22%29proce_000_%22%2C%2proce_144_%22%2C%2proce_1_%22%29proce_100_%22%2C%2proce_57777_%22%2C%2proce_0000_%22%29proce_123_%22%2C%2proce_123_%22%2C%2proce_123_%22%29proce_123_%22%2C%2proce_123_%22%2C%2'`

Comment: this works for the whole set. but I have thousands of rows. I need to iterate n times in loop and do this until the end of the loop.

Comment: @user1471980 do you want n number of strings or n rows in one string

Comment: @user1471980 I updated the answer based on your question update, do you want a list as output?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to deal with a large amount of data, Pandas offers a great page about it and describes an efficient way to create chunks: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html

**My advice is to go with a [Dask](https://dask.org/) implementation** to process chunks efficiently (locally, or prepare for even larger datasets by distributing compute on a cluster). **Dask comes with a DataFrame API** which looks like Pandas' one which will allow you to feel confortable using it.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
df1 = dd.read_csv('myfile1.csv')
df2 = dd.read_csv('myfile2.csv')
# do something with your dataframes
# combine them (append -- but you could also join etc.)
final_df = df1.append(df2)
```

You'll find numerous great examples here:

- https://tutorial.dask.org/04_dataframe.html
- https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-with-dask-for-an-ultra-fast-notebook-e2621c3769f

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to apply `.rolling` but to string columns. Modifying a bit from [Rolling sum with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541712/rolling-sum-with-strings).

```py
def create_chunk_string(dff):
    res_df = pd.concat(
        [dff['ProcId'].shift(-i).fillna('') for i in range(3)], 
        axis=1
    ).sum(axis=1)
    res_df = res_df.iloc[:-3+1].to_frame(name='ChunkStr')
    return dff.join(res_df, how='left')    

print(df.groupby('Metric').apply(create_chunk_string))

   Metric       ProcId            TimeStamp      Value                        ChunkStr
0     CPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00   1.445312     proce_123proce_126proce_123
1     CPU    proce_126  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.058320     proce_126proce_123proce_000
2     CPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.095274     proce_123proce_000proce_144
3     CPU    proce_000  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.019654       proce_000proce_144proce_1
4     CPU    proce_144  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.019841       proce_144proce_1proce_100
5     CPU      proce_1  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.234742                             NaN
6     CPU    proce_100  Mar-11-202211:00:00   5.329458                             NaN
7     GPU  proce_57777  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.253906  proce_57777proce_0000proce_123
8     GPU   proce_0000  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.019350    proce_0000proce_123proce_123
9     GPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.019501     proce_123proce_123proce_123
10    GPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00   2.324219     proce_123proce_123proce_123
11    GPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00  68.390366     proce_123proce_123proce_123
12    GPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.057781                             NaN
13    GPU    proce_123  Mar-11-202211:00:00   0.416667                             NaN
```

You might want to sort your dataframe before doing this.
Solution for adding the string in between and at the end of `ChunkStr` should be straightforward.